# Has MySQL caught up to SQL Server Express ( Specifically Stored Procedures) for a small e-commerce site running on AWS?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I apologize if this question has been asked. I could not find anything recent related to my question. I currently use SQL Server 2008r2 Express, PHP, and Apache on a single AWS EC2 micro virtual machine for a repository for both my software firewall, and my PHP website. All of my databases are within the 10GB requirement. I have relatively low traffic for the moment.

I am considering the change because of the resource hungry needs of SQL Server and the potential costs of having a dedicated machine instance for it, and I have not used MySQL in production before. I am also considering going with an outsourced DB but I am concerned with latency and performance. My options in that arena seem only to be SQL Azure, but I am concerned about sticker shock and latency.

I use several key words and features that I can't seem to find equivalents for on MySQL. Any alternative options are greatly appreciated!!!

I use the following features:

- Table
- Parameters
- XML Parsing
- Stored Procedures
- Geospatial Fields
- Full Text Search
- Custom functions

I use the following key words:

- RANK
- PARTITION BY
- OVER

I use the following syntax which I do no remember what it is called:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT x, y, z
   FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.key = Table.key

)T;
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you are using windowing functions (`rank()`, `partition by`) MySQL won't do it for you. You should consider PostgreSQL if you are looking for a free alternative to SQL Server: http://datachomp.com/archives/im-leaving-sql-server-for-postgres/

Comment: Thanks Vikram! However, I am very rusty on PL/SQL. Also I will admit I have not looked at the product in 6 years, it was pretty complicated at that time. Have things changed for the better?

Comment: What do you mean with PL/SQL? PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural langauge (although PostgreSQL's language is very similar). If you haven't looked at Postgres for 6 years - well it has come a **long** way since then. Do read the link I posted. (btw: my name is not Vikram...).

Comment: You might also want to read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630891/tips-for-sql-server-developer-picking-up-postgresql/4631695#4631695

Comment: Thanks and I apologize. I will take a read!

Comment: +1 to @a_horse_with_no_name on PostgreSQL - it really has gotten much better, though it's hard to beat SQL Server for tools and features that make your life easier. The old thinking was that PostgreSQL had more features but was slower, so MySQL was the best for web applications, but I don't think that's true, anymore. Most of the cloud-based databases are fairly expensive from what I've seen.

Comment: @RussellFox: the thinking that PG was slower that MySQL was never really true. It always ran circles around MySQL when (concurrent) updates came into play (although MySQL 5.1 and later got better in that area)

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from MySQL at all costs. Check out [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12364/6236) (holy crimoly!), [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12418/6236), or [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13175/mysql-is-null-is-not-null-misbehaving/13201) for examples of MySQL having problems that will drive you bonkers, waste your time, and generally make you wish you hadn't picked it.